# Sandbox Billing agreement is created via credit card but payment is not received

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am implementing Paypal recurring system to my project. The billing agreement is created successfully but payment is not received. Its just Showing status Created but payment is completed.

**Dashboard:**
[image]

Billing page:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer because I'm not allowed to comment yet.

With PayPal, the initial transaction with the service is to "Create" the payment record or profile. The response object for that transaction should contain a key/token that is then added to a URL that redirects the user to PayPal for authorization. Once authorized, you should see the payment.

Here is an example using Express Checkout:

[How to Create a Recurring Payments Profile with Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/)

You can see an example of the response object under Step 1:

```
Response
--------
TOKEN=EC%2d2B984685J43051234
&ACK=Success
```

And, the redirect URL in Step 2:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=InsertTokenHere
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Okay no problem !!!  I am creating agreement via Credit card my agreement is created but no payment received.